# Manipulating the HTTP header in WCF before HTTP authentication in HttpBinding

Tags: .net, wcf, http-headers, wcf-binding

This is in relation to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209795)

I am hosting this WCF service in a custom service host.  IIS is not an option.

Is there a way to inject an HTTP "Authenticate" header **in the server stack** (if it's missing) early on in the request process - such that a default user can be passed into the authentication/authorization process that I have in place for anonymous requests?

I need the SERVER to inject this on the receiving end - before further WCF processing...

I'm pretty sure I can do this with a custom BindingElement, or by extending the WebHttpBinding, but any examples or guidance would be greatly appreciated.  I can't find any examples of early header manipulation (pre authentication) in WCF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By implementing an IDispatchMessageInspector you can plug into the pipeline server side; and manipulate messages.

In the AfterReceiveRequest method you can add to Request.Headers quite happily.

Wrap it with a behaviour attribute and apply it to your service.

Answer (score -1):

I would type this out, but its a lot. So here is a good reference.

Avner Kashtan's blog post outlines what I "think" you're looking for. Hopefully this helps!

[Adding Custom Headers To Every WCF Call](http://weblogs.asp.net/avnerk/archive/2006/04/26/Adding-custom-headers-to-every-WCF-call-_2D00_-a-solution.aspx)

Comment: that is adding headers to outgoing wcf calls.  I need to add headers to INCOMING wcf calls.