# Accessing a WCF MessageHeader when OperationContext.Current is null

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a WCF that is being secured using a custom UserNamePasswordValidator.  I need to access  what normally would be available in:

```
OperationContext.Current.RequestContext.RequestMessage.Headers.To
```

so I can parse the URL.
However, OperationContext.Current is null.  Is there a way to get at the message header without OperationContext?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Yes, it is possible through Message Inspectors.**

The [OperationContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.operationcontext.aspx) is not available during the [UserNamePasswordValidator.Validate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.identitymodel.selectors.usernamepasswordvalidator.validate.aspx) method because it will be created later in the pipeline, when the call has been dispatched to the appropriate service method.

Normally you would intercept incoming and outgoing messages early in the WCF pipeline by using **[Message Inspectors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa717047.aspx)**. However this **won't work in your case**, since [Message Inspectors are invoked only after the request has successfully been authenticated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/209795/wcf-webhttp-mixed-authentication-basic-and-anonymous).

If you need to **inspect the incoming HTTP request before authentication**, your only option is to **host your WCF service in IIS running in ASP.NET Compatibility Mode**.
This way you'll be able to access the request's URL through the [HttpContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.aspx) class:

```
public override void Validate(string userName, string password)
{
    string url = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;
}
```

**Related resources:**

- [WCF Services and ASP.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa702682.aspx)
- [ASP.NET Compatibility Mode](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wenlong/archive/2006/01/23/516041.aspx)
- [HttpRequest.Url Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.url.aspx)

Comment: Did a quick test and hosted a service in ASP.NET Compatibility Mode on my local IIS and HttpContext.Current was still null.  Looks like I'll have to do Authentication in each service call :(

Comment: Looks like I can't do the Authentication in each service call... There is no native support for getting the user's password outside the UserNamePasswordValidator.Validate method.

Comment: Upgraded the service from .NET 3.5 to 4.0 and your solution worked.  Thanks!